# Getting a Private Key

Tags: private-key

1) When is a Private Key generated? 
2) Where is it generated? 
3) Where is it stored? 
4) How do I use the Private Key to release funds from 'non-spendable' status

Answer (score 4):

Non-spendable funds are simply funds that are not yours. Anyone who is telling you that funds are both yours and non-spendable is scamming you and you should stop talking to them.

The process of generating the private key takes place when the owner of the wallet creates the wallet. If you don't have the private key, it's not your wallet and anyone who is trying to tell you otherwise is trying to scam you.